# Is there a way to trigger Process Builder on record create/update ONLY when update is performed by a specific user via a specific Connected App?

Tags: rest-api, process-builder, connected-apps

Our middleware creates/updates records using the REST API. It authenticates with a specific integration user via a specific connected app.

I want to be able to trigger a Process Builder decision node ONLY when a record is created/updated by the specific integration user when they have authenticated via the specific connected app.

I've had a look at all the available variables in Process Builder and cannot see one that would work. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Edit: the integration user is used for a number of integrations. But I am only interested in create/updates done by the combination of **specific user + connected app** (ie: the connected app being used for authentication is important). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Probably by using $Username = <specific user>?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer. That user is used for other integrations, so that's why it needs to only be by that specific user AND the specific Connected App

Comment: Unless the connected App sets a value in the database indicating the source of the record, the answer is NO